# What guarantees are provided by DSE Graph transactions?

Tags: datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

DSE Graph supports the Gremlin transaction API , and the docs have some information about [transaction-specific options](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/reference/schema/refSchemaConfig.html) that can be set using the schema config API. The docs don't seem to have a lot of information yet on what a transaction "means", or what it guarantees. Presumably, they are not ACID transactions.

Does a graph transaction correspond perhaps to a Cassandra lightweight transaction? Or, does a graph transaction instead correspond to a CQL batch statement? Or is it something else entirely? What operations, if any, are atomic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DSE Graph transaction is similar to the batch statement components of C*.  DSE Graph abstracts the transaction concept from direct user control, vs. what Titan provided.  Anything sent into DSE Graph is considered a transaction and the same guaranties are provided.  You can see this simple git for an example/description of transaction guaranties - https://github.com/jlacefie/GraphTransactionExample

Also, note we are working on improving our documentation to provide more insight into transactions.  In the interim, you are welcome to ask direct questions via the DataStax Academy Graph slack channel - https://academy.datastax.com/slack